# Ubuntu 17.04 wifi not working and shown as unclaimed

Tags: networking, 17.04, realtek-wireless

I just installed Ubuntu 17.04 in dual boot alongside Windows 10, which was pre-installed. The dual boot is working well. I have a Lenovo ThinkPad E570.

Though, no wifi is showing up in the "Network" settings.

Under "Software & Updates" I was looking for my wifi under "Additional Drivers", but it is not shown there either.

I tried restarting the network service, as well as editing the /etc/NetworkManager/Networkmanager.conf , but nothing showed up.

When I type

```
lshw -C network
```

I get the output

```
 *-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Network controller
   product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: ioport:b000(size=256) memory:f2000000-f200ffff
```

Typing

```
rfkill list
```

gives me this output

```
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

without any wifi being shown.

When I type

```
lsusb
```

it shows me the connection of the

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:c024 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
```

which I suppose should be related to the wifi.

Does anyone have any idea what to do here?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Edit:

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
```

gives the output

```
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:c821]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:c024]
```

Comment: I believe your wireless device is PCI and not USB. May we also see: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: According to [this thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=229651), it's hardware that seems incompatible with Linux. Nothing we can do about lousy hardware, sorry. The key phrase to search for is `10ec:c821`.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with the same problem (same hardware but Xubuntu 16.04). This is not the solution (as I have not managed to solve it), but some links/info that I've come across in my searches that hopefully get us closer to the answer and might enable the experts to help us get there.

I believe we have the Realtek 8821CE Wireless card (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/379049/realtek-wifi-driver-problem-in-linux-mint-18-2).

It seems the card does not yet have a supported linux driver. I gathered this from this thread: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2371149 Praseodym's suggested trial solution from that thread (using 8887285-rtl8821ce_Test_2b.tar.bz2) did not work for me. It caused my computer to freeze and I had to restart with secure boot enabled.

As is indicated at the end of that thread, there might be a driver on someone's github page (or still under development?), but I don't know how to go about trying to install it:
https://github.com/endlessm/linux/commit/2baadff71422704848a39fba8849dde3222cb1bd

Hopefully experts can help us further. Afraid I don't understand much about these things.